# back button closes the application in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I use the following code to open another viewcontroller (in myviewcontroller1.m)

```
#import "contactvc.h"

contactvc *ii;

// ....

-(IBAction)passothervc:(id)sender
{
   //this code seems working OK.
   ii = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contactvc"];
   [self presentViewController:ii animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

and 
following code to return to main viewcontroller (in contactvc.m)

```
-(IBAction)backToMain:(id)sender
{
   [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Second view is opened OK but only an empty-black screen remains when I click back button. Probably application is down. There must be something that I don't know or missing.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contactvc.m use this code:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```